# Multiple browser testing with Geb/Spock via Gradle : usage of geb.env property

Tags: gradle, groovy, cross-browser, automated-tests, geb

I am currently working on testing a web app with Geb/Spock automated tests but I am facing a problem with `geb.env` property. If I had well understood, the values that `geb.env` can take are defined in `GebConfig.groovy` in `environments {}` statements. Am I right ?

So here is my environments definition in **GebConfig.groovy**:

```
    environments {

        chrome {
            driver = { new ChromeDriver() }
        }

        firefox {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe")
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile", "default")
            driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }
        }

        customFF {
            driver = {
                ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni()
                FirefoxProfile myProfile = profile.getProfile("ForPrintTests")
                myProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 0)
                myProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe")
                System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile", "ForPrintTests")
                new FirefoxDriver(myProfile)
            }
      } 
}

driver = {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe")
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile", "DefaultSelenium")
    new FirefoxDriver()
}
```

I need the `customFF` environment for a specific spec. So I wanted to execute this spec with `gradlew -Dgeb.env=customFF test --tests package.of.my.SpecificSpec` but when I run the command, the spec is still executed with default driver. That is why I commented the default driver definition and tried again and, of course, the build fail (so I guess the command option is not taken in account or not understood).

I tried to set it directly in `build.gradle` and run through `gradlew test --tests package.of.my.SpecificTest` but I get the same results. Here is my **build.gradle**:

```
ext {
    // The drivers we want to use
    drivers = ["firefox", "chrome"]

    ext {

        gebVersion = '1.1.1'
        seleniumVersion = '3.4.0'
        chromeDriverVersion = '2.24'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven {
        url("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
}

dependencies {

    testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'

    testCompile "org.gebish:geb-core:1.1.1"
    testCompile "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.4.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"

}

test{
    System.setProperty "geb.env", "customFF"
}
```

Am I doing completely wrong ? Should I use `geb.driver` instead of `geb.env` ? If so, how ? Because I should be facing the same issue than with `geb.env` (option not taken in account).

I can provide more information if needed. Thank you, in advance, for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set system properties on the `test` task explicitly as they are not automatically "passed" from the system properties set when running gradle because tests are run in a separate JVM (see first paragraph [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html)).

You can either hardcode it:

```
test {
    systemProperty "geb.env", "customFF"
}
```

Or "pass" all properties from the JVM running the build:

```
test {
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @erdi it works ! The environment is well loaded (but my configuration does not work). Correct me if I am wrong but I understand that `System.properties` refers to  properties of build's JVM whereas `systemProperty` or `systemProperties` refer to properties from "current" JVM (here test's one). Is that it ?

Comment: For the record, if my code wasn't working properly it was because of the definition of the profile. The line `System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile", "ForPrintTests")` override changes in the preferences before. I came back to the simple
    FirefoxProfile myProfile = new FirefoxProfile()
    //preferences changes
    new FirefoxDriver(myProfile)`